# How to move a mdadm software raid-5 attached to a 5 bay NAS enclosure from one PC to another?

Tags: raid, mdadm, nas

I have a 40TB (32TB available, RAID-5) 5-bay Yottamaster NAS enclosure that I was able to setup on one of my work linux stations. The NAS enclosure uses a USB type C to transfer data (up to 10Gbps).

After getting `mdadm` setup on it in RAID-5, I was able to transfer a large dataset onto it. Our Linux stations are used for data analysis that uses GPUs for most applications.

Since another user is currently using the GPUs, I would like to just be able to unplug this NAS and plug it in to another system ready for use immediately. I have the `mdadm.conf` and `fstab` copied, however, `mdadm --assemble --scan` does not detect anything, nor does it seem my drives are being recognized by the new system. When I unplug and plug it back in to my original system, the drive is assembled and mounted automatically.

Does anyone have any ideas or know how to achieve this? Thanks!

UPDATE: I fixed this issue and another which was most likely the culprit. The 5-bay Yottamaster has it's own power supply, so the drives and USB port not receiving enough power is out of question. After rebooting, the copied 'fstab' and 'mdadm.conf' entries were enough for all drives to be detected. However, after days of data transfer, my 'dmesg' was flooded with uas-handler errors resulting in data corruption and mdadm kicking disks off the array. A fix for this was to just disable the UAS by following this [Raspberry Pi Sticky](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=245931) I found. I have not noticed any reduction in read/write speeds and the NAS is stable now.

Comment: A 5-bay enclosure probably cannot get enough power from USB only. Is the enclosure powered up when you plug in the USB cable, so the system can immediately detect the drives without waiting for them to spin up first? It should be visible in `lsusb` listing - can you see it?

Comment: I have since figured out the issue - the system just needed to be rebooted. However, it is interesting that you mention USB power because I am having another issue which seems to be related. The enlosure has it's own power supply but after a few days of large data transfer, it appears the UAS handler/USB-C port on our machine fails and needs to restart. This makes mdadm believe a drive has failed, and kicks it off the array and a bunch of error messages pop up. A simple reboot of the NAS seems to fix it and it starts trying to rebuild the spare. Any ideas what might be going on?